# Hide div on date-time picker click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this image when i select value from drop down and select dates then container is displayed and then when i select row from table data then cont and sumdata div is displayed now i want when i select again dates from date picker then want to hide all divs ... and when click on search then want to display container

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         $(function () {

             var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
             var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth();
             var currentDay = (new Date).getDate();
             $('#fromdate').datepicker({
                 showSecond: false,
                 timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                 minDate: new Date((currentYear - 2), 12, 1),
                 //minDate: 0,
                 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                 maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay),
                 //maxDate: new Date((currentYear + 1), 12, 1),
                 onSelect: function (selectedDate) {

                     // Start Date
                     var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

                     //startDate.SetHours(0);
                     //startDate.setMinutes(0);
                     //startDate.setSeconds(0);

                     $('#todate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDate);
                     $('#todate').datepicker('setDate', startDate);

                     // End Date
                     var enddate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                     enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate() + 60);
                    // endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 2);
                     $('#todate').datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', enddate);
                 }
             });



        $('#todate').datepicker({
             showSecond: false,
             timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
             minDate: new Date((currentYear - 2), 12, 1),
             minDate: 0,
             dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
             maxDate: '+30',
             //maxDate: endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 2)


         });

       $('#fromdate').on('click', function () {
              $("#tabledata").hide();
             $('#container').hide();
             $("#cont").hide();
             $("#sumdata").hide();
             $("#sum").hide();
         });

         $("#todate").datepicker({
             onSelect: function (dateText) {
                 $("#tabledata").hide();
                 $('#container').hide();
                 $("#cont").hide();
                 $("#sumdata").hide();
                 $("#sum").hide();
             }
         });

     });
  </script>
```

Comment: You can use `onselect` event of datepicker.

Comment: where i do this after success or in if else ??? @Loading..

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onselect` option to execute any `JavaScript` transformations

e.g.:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    // hide your divs
    $('.mydivs').hide();
  }
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7dy0wduc/

Comment: @rebmaamber - it's not an `ajax` event. it's a `datepicker` option. you should place it in your `datepicker` create statement.

Comment: and i do this but this is not working .. what i write instead of datetext?

Comment: @rebmaamber - what isn't working? why are you running `datepicker()` so many times?

Comment: i dont know .. i use because  i set some conditions on calendar

Comment: @rebmaamber - if you don't know what's not working how can I possibly help you? one thing is for certain, you have to re-write your code and make sure that you are only running `datepicker()` once for fromdate and once for todate. after that you can use the `onselect` option on both of them to do any transformations you need. good luck!

Comment: i mean the code you provided is not working.. when i click on datepicker then divs not hide

Comment: @rebmaamber - my code works perfectly, but you are running `datepicker()` more than once with different options each time

Comment: yes because i set some conditions on date-picker thats why i do this

Comment: now look at this .. https://jsfiddle.net/7dy0wduc/2/  if content is display and when i click on datepicker then divs not hide..

Comment: @rebmaamber - which "divs don't hide"?

Comment: all. have you my check js fiddle?

Comment: @rebmaamber - the fiddle only hides the divs when the 1st datepicker has its value reset. it's just an example. however, in the `onSelect` of the 2nd `datepicker` **you** have added this: `$("#divs").hide();` which will **always** hide `<div id="divs">fdgdfg</div>`

Comment: i think all divs are display ..in short i just want to hide div when i click on datepicker and your code is not helpful for this you may check again my js fiddle and in you js fiddle you already hide div in css . .somedivs {
  display: none;
}
where as i want to hide on datepicker click

Comment: i dont want to display value on dates selection .. i want to hide on datepicker selection not dates ..

Comment: @rebmaamber - what's the difference between "dates selection" and "datepicker selection" ? you're not making any sense. I've tried my best to help you but I suspect there's a language barrier at play here.